# R - compute percent change in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to compute the percent change of precipitation relative to a baseline value for all columns of a data frame.

This is a sample of my data:

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2026, 2027, 2028, 
2029, 2030, 2031, 2032, 2033, 2034, 2035, 2036, 2037, 2038, 2039, 
2040), CanESM2 = c(1062.28463487013, 1081.79875965293, 954.918023984367, 
1091.10825280531, 1015.6686025322, 1004.68487579451, 900.568853780764, 
944.304316538189, 1131.29811907252, 880.640168198752, 1036.79227239276, 
1104.19653571418, 1016.11848396336, 964.309534825316, 995.667089383537, 
949.590669553214, 1031.46345256665, 950.988527516706, 997.957590593111, 
1021.01557120052, 1014.29734436525, 1100.42743380135, 990.129571074739, 
988.028837921423, 852.09126335109, 984.607515553816, 994.858568349016, 
924.28298500481, 1030.62630719001, 971.449059906356), `GFDL-ESM2M` = c(939.797764384418, 
862.438744527484, 833.258752796628, 694.001972600954, 939.25225566724, 
788.443578230132, 769.624653964961, 922.180523767384, 815.569903819933, 
923.2684778161, 973.312551235934, 1000.87827680745, 722.100345996542, 
754.896724902162, 946.691351890564, 1108.37198079835, 776.359064574635, 
877.332713415863, 641.223755372774, 891.215662326288, 840.29228301442, 
809.219713604778, 890.788503113143, 816.101567557099, 700.315931425182, 
974.495291193691, 774.889934251068, 687.874812729862, 890.626164086368, 
925.821083978776), `MRI-CGCM3` = c(963.714630100705, 1039.90725638013, 
986.808066989304, 952.912003762131, 1038.96522172, 1097.12269863514, 
1152.25870240938, 1039.16198171388, 1126.11992922617, 1113.46311136123, 
1097.59899557621, 1133.00511613898, 1060.2239913503, 1080.25928340702, 
999.790532217113, 1111.90775837155, 1103.01247472501, 1122.86866008689, 
966.542898921792, 1121.08812228037, 1126.70968803791, 1237.48721073746, 
1120.73913534847, 1065.51575339606, 1120.41655349731, 1056.45756230661, 
978.781090360169, 1215.56226961328, 1100.79315092804, 1187.63969015419
), `NorESM1-M` = c(1035.9629164267, 1127.66908751496, 1145.04203724642, 
1073.79587400944, 1108.66027421689, 1081.31321431081, 991.997929494315, 
970.820426144731, 900.132816323447, 993.967016211343, 1093.47915064086, 
1062.25356500083, 1009.98847866058, 1047.23083263362, 1006.76468700444, 
953.814034566967, 1040.03729133431, 1015.64394700637, 971.068915900834, 
1019.70349949653, 967.3858486578, 1012.08374091682, 1024.64494944056, 
1008.14540593558, 1036.2929410322, 948.484238020871, 991.503419342391, 
1008.67344263059, 989.210959828228, 1024.22494449965), inmcm4 = c(1156.30514792346, 
978.782707800559, 800.222094903299, 936.254681298492, 876.693978852088, 
897.739287157671, 909.653028295674, 904.362882202918, 804.087073124877, 
910.965404178024, 852.324516060155, 823.608663016503, 793.372757614206, 
935.721565622802, 910.427470364702, 831.026191632682, 912.055279276787, 
953.783713646985, 1003.06614105855, 915.388398109226, 1002.55859526363, 
882.401185901887, 936.531046202423, 952.577307893596, 858.244066168409, 
962.797113287339, 816.732411218346, 769.801340383127, 758.534824983789, 
931.961373442904)), .Names = c("Year", "CanESM2", "GFDL-ESM2M", 
"MRI-CGCM3", "NorESM1-M", "inmcm4"), row.names = 31:60, class = "data.frame")
```

As you can see, I have five different observations of annual precipitation.

For each year (row) and column, how can I compute the percent change relative to some reference value, for example 1100mm?

If I were to write a function, it would be something like:

```
(x-1100)/1100
```

where `x` is each element of the data frame, excluding the first column.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
 (df[,-1] -1100)/1100
```

The final implementation depends on your desired output, *e.g.* whether you want to

- overwrite the columns of your df

  ```
   df[,-1] <- (df[,-1] -1100)/1100
  ```
- create a new data.frame

  ```
  new.df <- cbind( df[,1], (df[,-1] -1100)/1100 )
  ```

If that's not, what you are looking for, reducing the sample data to just a couple of years/rows might help others to answer.

Comment: It worked, but is there any way to keep the first column, in spite of ignoring it for the calculations?

Comment: Sure, i have extended my answer a bit.